# Unable to get IdentityUser data from ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

I am developing an application in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I am using Identity with built-in user accounts. Now I am trying to develop a user maintenance module in this application where I'm stuck. I am unable to fetch the data inside the controller. Here is my code:

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(config => {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    }
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h2>Application users</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.Name</p>
}
```

**ApplicationUsersController.cs:**:

```
public class ApplicationUsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ApplicationUsersController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Administrator/ApplicationUsers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.ApplicationUsers.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

`_context.ApplicationUsers.ToListAsync()` is not returning any results, although there is data in my AspNetUsers table.

Comment: Can you share your `ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: @ipinak: I added my ApplicationDbContext in the question. FYI: When I change the first line in my ApplicationDbContext from
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
to
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

it does work, but then my register page is throwing this error:
**InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to use custom `ApplicationUser` for your Identity instead of default `IdentityUser`.You need to make some changes after declaring the model.

1.In dbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

2.In startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(config => {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
...
```

3.In your /Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Answer (score 0):

`IdentityUser` is not a part of your `dbContext`. You need to use `UserManager<IdentityUser>` instead.

Your `ApplicationUsersController` class should look like this

```
public class ApplicationUsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationUsersController(ApplicationDbContext context,
                                      UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // GET: Administrator/ApplicationUsers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _userManager.Users.Cast<ApplicationUser>().ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dusan, thanks for your reply, but that will not work for me: InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Cnock.Models.ApplicationUser]'.

Comment: I added some extra fields to the IdentityUser class. By doing this, the controller is returning an IdentityUser instead of an ApplicationUser.

Comment: I forgot to cast the list elements to `ApplicationUser`. Now I fixed the answer, so try now

Comment: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser' to type 'Cnock.Models.ApplicationUser'. :-(

Comment: The problem is that `_userManager` doesn't load properties of `ApplicationUser` table and `_context` doesn't load properties of `IdentityUser` table. My suggestion is to remove parent class on `ApplicationUser` and put a property which will act as a foreign key to an `IdentityUser`. So when you want to use data from `IdentityUser` use `_userManager` and when you want to use data from `ApplicationUser` use `_context`